# Which Keyword search Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search

I have a list of Movies.

```
eg:
Iron Man - 2008
Iron Man 2 - 2010
Iron Man 3 - 2013
Shawshank Redemption - 2000
```

I want to implement a search algorithm based on keywords. If I enter Iron, all 3 Iron Man movies should come up. Iron Man 2010, Only Iron Man 2 should come in the results.

I thought about TF-IDF, but it doesn't take order of words into consideration. ie, if there is a movie `Man Iron`, it will be have same ranking as `Iron Man` even though the keyword entered is `Iron Man`.

Which algorithm works best in this scenario, in which order of the occouring words is also considered?

Comment: Did you consider using Trie data structure and search will be very simple. Only if the search input as correct as the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.
Break all the search result with spaces

```
 #algo 
 movie_list = ['Iron man 2008', 'Iron man 2010','Iron man 2013']
 partial_results = {}
 i=0
 movie = "Iron man 2010"
 words = movie.split(" ")

 for a_movie in movie_list:
     print_unique_movie = true
     for each_word in words:
         if each_word in a_movie:
             partial_results[i] = a_movie
             continue
         else
             print_unique_movie = false
     i +=1
     if print_movie:
          print a_movie
     else:
          for key,value in partial_results.iteritems():
              print value
```

Though surely it's a very basic way. You can start optimizing by using regex instead. Also if its on a OS level you can use file indexing.